# Rails Resourceful Routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my rails app, I use resourceful routes for the basic CRUD functions.  But in some cases I'm adding new views and methods to my controllers (eg. specific reporting functions).  Do these get automatically included in the resourceful routes?  Or do I have to to a get or match line in routes.rb for each one?

Here is how I'm going with routes.rb now... It just seems that if I have to explicitly specify everything, this is going to get unweildy as the app grows...

```
  resources :procedures

  resources :headlines

  devise_for :users

  resources :services

  resources :headlines  

  get  "welcome/index" 
  get "welcome/profile"
  get "welcome/kpi"
  get "welcome/inventory"
  get "public/index" 
  match "insurancelist" => "appointments#insurancelist"


  get "admin/index" 
  get "dentrix/index"
  get "dexis/index"
  get "eaglesoft/index"
  get "reports/index"
  get "reports/dentist"
  get "reports/office"
  get "reports/collections"


  resources :patients

shallow do
   resources :locations do
    resources :practitioners do
      resources :timecards
      resources :appointments
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: No, they don't get "automatically added". You can [add resourceful routes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read about routes in the official Rails Guides [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

And here some quick tip for your question (as I see you would like to add some none-REST actions to your resources).

Let's see. For example, you have a Project model and `projects` resources. And you want to add `print` action for project item (in that action you will prepare report to be printed on paper, for example), and `published` action for the whole projects resource (as a selecting action for some kind of reports only):

You should write to your `routes.rb` next lines:

```
resources :projects do
  collection do
    get :published
  end

  member do
    get :print
  end
end
```

That code gives you next routes:

```
GET    /projects           => projects#index
GET    /projects/published => projects#published
GET    /projects/new       => projects#new
POST   /projects           => projects#create
DELETE /projects/:id       => projects#destroy
PUT    /projects/:id       => projects#update
GET    /projects/:id       => projects#show
GET    /projects/:id/edit  => projects#edit
GET    /projects/:id/print => projects#print
```

Answer (score 1):

Those additional routes do not get included in the resourceful routes. With the routes in your example, there really is no way to condense them, unfortunately, and they will each require an individual line in the routes file.